# How to create and set oval icon for the JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, icons, jmenuitem

I wanted to create JMenu with an oval icon for my `JMenuItem`

So I know I should use:

```
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(title);
item.setIcon(icon)
```

But how to create that kind of icon:

[image]

Comment: just google images of dots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make your own `Icon`-implementation:

```
public class OvalIcon implements Icon {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Color color;

    public OvalIcon(int w, int h, Color color) {
        if((w | h) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal dimensions: "
                    + "(" + w + ", " + h + ")");
        }
        this.width  = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.color  = (color == null) ? Color.BLACK : color;
    }
    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Color temp = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
        g.setColor(temp);
    }
    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) provides you with a `ShapeIcon` which allows you to create Icons of many different shapes. For example:

```
Shape round = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 10, 10);
ShapeIcon red = new ShapeIcon(round, Color.RED);
ShapeIcon green = new ShapeIcon(round, Color.GREEN);
```